# Restoring a Password in Single-User Mode?

Tags: macos, passwords, root

I had changed a password for an account titled **student** with no password by doing this in single user mode,

```
fsck -fy

mount -uw /

passwd student
```

The password now is student, but when I try to change back the password to no password again, it says "no changed added". How do I restore it back to no password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this [post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/15237/change-account-password-to-blank).

> The `passwd` command rejects the idea that you can have a 0 length password.
>
> Instead use `dscl` which is more accepting of the notion that the password is nothing.
>
> `dscl . -passwd /Users/foo`
>
> You can press enter to make the new password blank and then may get an error and have to enter the old password if you are not root but once you authenticate (or are root already) the blank password will be written.

Answer (score 0):

To delete password from an account issue `passwd -d <username>`. <- bad. apple does not have this

Comment: When I issued it, it said *-d* was an illegal option. Perhaps change your syntax?

Comment: Sorry, mistaken it for linux passwd syntax.

Apples store the password info in the /etc/passwd file }which is only used when booting to single user mode. There should be hashed value, which you could simply delete. In the ordinary boot, the passwords are stored in the DirectoryService.